# Unity 3d Menu's

Tags: menu, unity-game-engine

New to unity3d and I've been asked to participate in developing a game in it. I'm in charge of the menus of the game. Does anybody know how we can make menus in the compiled window of the game. Not menus with the GUI library but standard window menus like File,Edit,Options etc.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no built in way to do this, according to http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/209198/how-to-make-a-file-edit-preference-menu.html

Comment: Just use the GUI.Button() API mentioned in [@FunctionR's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24051232/778118) and it should be pretty easy to roll your own... You can easily control the style and location of all buttons.

Answer (score 1):

In games the menus are usually part of the game not a windows-form. You normally have the menu scene with buttons like Options, Exit, Credits, and Play.

My friends and I built this game in a 24 hour hackathon; you can see an example of what the menu looks like at the start of this YouTube video: [**ClockWork**](http://youtu.be/6wfmfxc8ufw).

I remember having a lot of fun making that 3D menu. You have options, you could make a simple 2D menu with textures or use 3D. You can start by reading the [GUI.Button API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html). You can also add a song to your menu. I also suggest you look at examples of menus for other games.